# PGFplots standalone colormap problem

Tags: pgfplots, color

I'm trying to create a colormap for one of my documents. To test and see what this colormap looks like, I use the `\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone` command.

However, when using this command, the upper part of the colormap is grayed out when it should be red. On the other hand, when I use my colormap in a graph, the colors are correct.  (Same with a predefined color map.)

Do you know what the problem is?
Should options be added to the `\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone` command?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={mycolormap}{
        rgb255=(80,80,80)
        rgb255=(255,255,255)
        rgb255=(230,40,25)
    },
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[colormap name=mycolormap]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis, colormap name=mycolormap]
       \addplot3[surf, samples=50, domain=-8:8]
            {sin(deg(sqrt(x^2+y^2)))/sqrt(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[colormap name=viridis]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis, colormap name=viridis]
        \addplot3[surf, samples=50, domain=-8:8]
             {sin(deg(sqrt(x^2+y^2)))/sqrt(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For me, using PGFPlots v1.17 the colormaps look perfectly fine ...

Comment: Which pdf reader do yo use? And perhaps you can provide the output pdf, therefore others can check it the problem comes from pdf file or pdf reader.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ By default, I do not use Adobe Reader, however after your messages, I downloaded it and actually the content displayed correctly. So it’s a flaw on the PDF reader that I used. Thank you for your help!